# Need to merge one Postgres relational database into another; same exact schema, foreign keys are issue

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, scripting, relational

I have one relational Postgres 8.4 database that needs to be merged to a second one. Actually, I just need to merge specific table rows needed to represent a certain class of domain objects in our webapp. The problem is that the webapp uses object relational mapping and therefore all the tables are tied together via use of id columns and foreign key constraints.

My problem is 
1) I want to only append the rows from the first database to the second for specific tables, not all tables
2) Since these tables are tied together by the auto-incremented id column, and these columns are all obviously going to be offset in the destination db, I will need to replace that foreign key column reference value with the offset one

I can of course use a long and complex script to do this, but I was wondering if there are any automated tools, libraries, etc that could speed this process up.

Any and all comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How will you know which record from source maps to which one on the target? Anyway, have a look at Kettle and this approach http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Insert+-+Update

Comment: This is just a data migration, so I don't need to retain any auto incremented identifiers, if that's what you're asking. I just need to grab rows from all interconnected tables in DB1, then dump these  rows into the new database, and reconnect their ids (via foreign keys) in DB2. Certainly nothing to conceptually difficult, it just seems like there should be a tool already out there for a task like this.

Comment: You can do that with Pentaho. Load the master tables. first. Then load the child tables. Use the lookup component from Pentaho to get the parent ids for the child records (do lookup against the target db tables).

Comment: Any tips on a guide or reference on how to do this? I have never used Pentaho before.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho/Kettle has 3 important pieces - Input (DB1 in our case), changes/modifications/transformations (none in your case) and output (DB2 in your case). It will be a very long post if I try to walk through the process. You may take 4-5 hours to install the SW and learn the basics. But once you do that, you can use it for this and much more. I use it for a lot of "data movement" activities and found it to be easy to learn and use.
You will need the input/DW combination (marked in red box in the image) for the master tables. Then use the input, lookup and output components for child tables. 
[image]This link to a sample chapter should also help.

[Example](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9546_PDI%20Beginner%27s%20guide_SampleChapter.pdf)